# My mac won't recognize my headset

Tags: headphones, microphone

Since Apple change my motherboard last week, my early 2011 MBP 15" won't recognize the mic of my headset... I tried to reboot, search in the settings panel but I can't make it work...

I tried in both holes, in and out (it used to work with both) with no success...

What else can I try ?

Comment: Resetting your SMC might help.

Answer (score 1):

New motherboard comes with new SMC controller.

I would suggest your run a Reset-SMC on yours to correctly identify your hardware.